# Java Convention for file/media upload location

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

I have searched around and haven't found anything very specific.  I know that it should sit outside the war.  My application is built on Spring and works under Tomcat.  Should the directory location stay within Tomcat /opt/tomcat or can I put it in /var/www/projectname (I prefer the latter)?

Might be over analyzing but I would much rather learn the convention then to create something new. I think by default it puts me in tomcats bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no *convention*. Choose a location that is accessible. If you control the installation, give that location group/user access permissions and start your process with that user.

Comment: I figured that was the case since I hadn't really found anything.  It seems to make the most sense to keep it within tomcat. Thanks for the quick response!